# RecyclerView onClick in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new android learner, I'm trying to make a **RecyclerView** contains of List of (Stories Title, and Stories images).
When you click on an item in the RecyclerView it should open a new activity called *ChildrenStoriesPreview* contains of *ScrollView* which have *ImageView* to put the Story Image in it and *TextView* to put the Text of the Story in it.
the problem is that I don't know how to set **ocItemClickListener** to know which item is clicked and how the new activity will contain information depending on this item? Could you please help me?

**here is my Main.kt**

```
class MainChildrenStories : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_children_stories)

    var childrenStoriesArraylist = ArrayList<ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView>()
    childrenStoriesArraylist.add(ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView("Story1", R.drawable.pic1))
    childrenStoriesArraylist.add(ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView("Story2", R.drawable.pic2))
    childrenStoriesArraylist.add(ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView("Story3", R.drawable.pic3))

    children_stories_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)

    val childrenStoriesAdapter = ChildrenStoriesAdapter(childrenStoriesArraylist)
    children_stories_recyclerview.adapter = childrenStoriesAdapter

childrenStoriesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : ChildrenStoriesAdapter.ClickListener {
        override fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View) {

    //The App Crash here
            if (pos == 0){
                my_text_view.text = "Story number 1"
                my_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1)
            }else if (pos == 1){
                my_text_view.text = "Story number 2"
                my_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2)
            }
            val intent = Intent(this@MainChildrenStories, ChildrenStoryPreview::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    })

   }
}
```

**MyRecyclerView Class**

```
data class ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView(var mStoryName: String, var mStoryImage: Int)
```

**My RecyclerView Adapter Class**

```
class ChildrenStoriesAdapter(var myArrayList: ArrayList<ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildrenStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

lateinit var mClickListener: ClickListener

fun setOnItemClickListener(aClickListener: ClickListener) {
    mClickListener = aClickListener
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.children_stories_list, p0, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return myArrayList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    var infList = myArrayList[p1]
    p0.storyName.text = infList.mStoryName
    p0.storyImage.setImageResource(infList.mStoryImage)
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        mClickListener.onClick(adapterPosition, v)
    }

    val storyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStoryName) as TextView
    val storyImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChildrenStories) as ImageView

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
}

interface ClickListener {
    fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View)
  }
}
```

**My new Activity To show Details of the Story**

```
class ChildrenStoryPreview : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_children_story_preview)

   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question
[Click Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219825/android-kotlin-how-to-add-click-listener-to-recyclerview-adapter/54222687#54222687)

Comment: @BhoominNaik Thank you for your help. I updated my code above depending on your answer, I still have a problem that when I use  `if (pos == 0){
                my_text_view.text = "Story number 1"
                my_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1)
            }` the App crash, but when i remove this part of code it works but the new activity will have the same pic and text for all positions, how can I Change text and picture in **ChildrenStoryPreview** Activity?

Comment: Finally I solved it by using `intent.putExtra("Key", pos)` to send the position to the other activity and in the other activity I used if statment to change text and it worked. Thank you Bhoomin

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Event Listener to Adapter constructor also to viewholder to catch view holder (items) clicks.

```
class ChildrenStoriesAdapter(var myArrayList: ArrayList<ChildrenStoriesRecyclerView>
                                     var clickListener:MyClickListener?) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildrenStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        ...
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
              val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.children_stories_list, p0, false)
              return ViewHolder(v, clickListener)
        }
    ...

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, clickListener:MyClickListener?) : 
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener?.myClickedFun(...) }
    ...

   class ChildrenStoryPreview : AppCompatActivity(), MyClickListener {
         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_children_story_preview)
         }
         override fun myClickedFun(...) {
         ...
        }
    }
```

Later init adapter like
    ..

```
 val childrenStoriesAdapter = ChildrenStoriesAdapter(childrenStoriesArraylist, this)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my code above, I still have a problem that when I use  `if (pos == 0){
                my_text_view.text = "Story number 1"
                my_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1)
            }` the App crash, but when i remove this part of code it works but the new activity will have the same pic and text for all positions, how can I Change text and picture in **ChildrenStoryPreview** Activity?

Comment: It didn't give me error the app open with out any error put when I click on item 1 or 2  at RecyclerView which I made (if) for them; the app stoped and closed. when I click at any other item it opens the CheldrenStoryPreview Activity without any problem

Comment: when I try to debug at line `my_text_view.text = "Story number 2"` This what shows in logcat ...  EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mohamedali.coco, PID: 21476
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: my_text_view must not be null
        at com.mohamedali.coco.ChildrenStories.MainChildrenStories$onCreate$1.onClick(MainChildrenStories.kt:97)
        at com.mohamedali.coco.ChildrenStories.ChildrenStoriesAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(ChildrenStoriesAdapter.kt:39)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) ...

Comment: Finally I solved it by using `intent.putExtra("Key", pos)` to send the position to the other activity and in the other activity I used if statment and it worked. Thank you Narek